# Derivative In A Point

Tags: calculus

When looking the function at 
$y=2x-x\sqrt{x}$ where parallel to the x-axis we get:

$$0=2-(\sqrt{x}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}})$$
$$0=2-\sqrt{x}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$0=4\sqrt{x}-3x$$

$$0=\sqrt{x}(4-3\sqrt{x})$$

So $x=0$ or $x=\frac{16}{9}$, wolfram does not show $x=0$ as a solution, why is that? the function is defined at $x=0$?

Answer (score 1):

multiplying your equation by $$\sqrt{x}\ne 0$$ we get
$$0=2\sqrt{x}-(x+x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$x\sqrt x=x^{1+1/2}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2-\dfrac{3x^{3/2-1}}2$$

Answer (score 0):

$x=0$ is not an answer and doesn't outcome by setting derivation to 0.

$$f(x)=2x-x^{3\over 2}\to f^{'}(x)=2-{3\over 2}x^{1\over 2}\to x={16\over 9}$$